# WPF prevent Owner window to be used

Tags: wpf, showdialog, owner, ownership

I am using WPF with C#.
I have a windows that is full screened. Upon this window I open a Dialog.
My Dialogs are just another Window that is designed different and are centered on this Owner.

During the first Dialog, I have a button that closes this dialog but opens another one.
I achieve this like this:

```
Window w = new FinalScreen();
w.Owner = this.Owner;
w.Topmost = true;
w.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

No matter if the first dialog is called using Show or ShowDialog, the second dialog is not TopMost, meaning my Main Window that is shown behind can be clicked.

What I get is that when this dialog is open centered on the main Window, the user can click the rear Buttons that are on the main Window that are exposed (not covered by the Dialog).

How can I block that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your might be better off with a "Wizard" interface with 2 pages.
There is a sample that covers that here:
[WPF Wizard Sample at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972123.aspx)